# Wordpress portfolio jumps strangely in Firefox

Tags: wordpress, firefox, portfolio

http://www.moef.dk/cases/

Anybody know why this looks so weird in Firefox, when the page looks fine in Safari and Chrome? Any help is really appreciated!

/ Soren

Answer (score 0):

Remove float left from this class.

```
        .container .column, .container .columns {
             float: left;
        }
```